# Test services with real backend in angular

Tags: angular, testing, testbed

I want to test a service, which calls a real backend url and can not find the solution for it. My service has to call data from server and I want to be sure, that the data comes to the service and the service handle it right.

So here is just a simple example of my Login Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
/**
 * The token, which will be stored on the localStorage.
 */
public token: string;
//Eventemitter, for updating the navigation, when the user logs in
@Output() loggedInEm:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();


constructor(private http: Http) {
    // set token if saved in local storage
    var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    this.token = currentUser && currentUser.token;
}

login(_mail, _pass): Observable<number> {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    var data = {
        mail: _mail,
        pass: _pass
    };
    return this.http.post('/login', JSON.stringify(data), {
        headers : headers
    }).map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        this.logged = res;
    });
}

public loggedIn() : boolean {
    return this.logged;
}
```

This is how I want to test it:

```
describe('Login Service', () => {

    let loginService: LoginService;

    beforeEach(() =>  {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
            ],
            providers: [
                LoginService
            ],
            imports: [
                FormsModule,
                IonicModule
            ],
        });
        inject([LoginService], (service) => {
            loginService = service;
        });
    });


    it("Should login user", () => {
        loginService.login("mail@mail.ru", "123456");
        let loggedIn = loginService.loggedIn();
        expect(loggedIn).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

But I get following error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'login' of undefined, so the service must be undefined. I could mock the service, but I want to work it with the real database, which I have on my backend server.

So what could be the problem and how can I solve it?

Kind regards,

Andrej

Comment: Maybe you forgot to import `HttpModule` into testing module?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
it("Should login user", () => {
    loginService.login("mail@mail.ru", "123456").subscribe(value => {
      let loggedIn = loginService.loggedIn();
      expect(loggedIn).toBe(true);
      done();
    });
})
```

Comment: It says, the same :(